# function declar of recursive power() gives "RangeError: Max call stack size exc" while function expr of identical power() runs fine

Tags: javascript, node.js

So i was reading through "Eloquent javascript", trying out some of the examples when I came across this:

the following code is a copy from the recursive power() function defined under Chapter 3 "Functions":

```
function power(base, exponent) {
    if(exponent == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return base * power(base, exponent-1);
}

console.log(power(2, 2));
```

when I run the snip with nodejs I get "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" with the pointer pointing to the character on the relevant line:

```
function power(base, exponent) {
              ^
```

in the explanation.

Running:

```
nodejs --stack-size=5000 power.js
```

yields the same result, although that should be an ocean of stack for the task defined.

Now when I change the code to:

```
var power = function(base, exponent) {
    //identical code here
}
```

running the file with node executes without any problems when the function is a function expression. I looked around, but most stack error posts I found related to people trying things that could actually overflow the stack (gigantic arrays, ill-defined base cases, etc), not computing 2².

I'm at a loss at how the stack could run out on that line of code; I don't see the logic in that. it's part of a larger file, where I just "doodle" javascript while I'm reading the ebook. But even then, that file has less than 70 lines of code in it (line that where the error is thrown is ln:58).

Anybody experienced in js and node that encountered something like this?

I'm running nodejs v0.10.25 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I wonder if it's a problem that your function has the same name as your `.js` file.

Comment: that was just for illustration, the real file is called "sketchblock.js"

Comment: Try and run the function in its own separate `.js` file.  This could shed some light on the issue.

Comment: This algorithm is slow. Better use [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Comment: .../Chapter_3/Tryout/test.js:1
n (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { function power(base, exp                                         
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded                                                             is what shows up when run in a seperate file

Comment: @oriol thanks for the advice, but it doesn't really pertain tomy initial question.

Comment: also, when I change the order of console log and the declaration the error also occurs, but without the (what I believe is node related) n(...) function preceding it. So I'm guessing it's node related? i'll keep digging.